# django Form values are empty

Tags: django

I have a problem with the home page displaying form values. Although on the search page the values are fine. What could be the problem here? I copied the same form from the search page to the homepage but still, it doesn't work, the values are empty. Any hint is appreciated, thank you!

search page:

```
 <form action="{% url 'search' %}">
                    <div class='flx around px'>
                        <input type='text' id='search-keyword' class='search-keyword form-control'
                            placeholder='keywords (pool,garage)'>
                        <select name='area' id='search-area' class='form-control'>
                            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" selected>Area(All)</option>
                            {% for key,value in area_choices.items %}
                            <option value="{{ key }}" {% if key == values.area %} selected {% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
                            {% endfor%}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class='flx around'>
                        <select name="bedrooms" class="form-control">
                            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" selected>Bedrooms(All)</option>
                            {% for key,value in bedroom_choices.items %}
                            <option value = "{{ key }}"
                            {% if key == values.bedrooms %} 
                            selected
                            {% endif %}
                            >{{ value }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                        <select name="price" class="form-control ">
                            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" selected>Price(All)</option>
                            {% for key,value in price_choices.items %}
                            <option value = "{{ key }}"
                            {% if key == values.price %}
                            selected
                            {% endif %}
                            
                            >{{ value }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type = "submit" class='btn fntmk my2 size'>Search&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-search size"></i></button>
                </form>
```

home page:

```
 <form action="{% url 'search' %}">
                    <div class = 'flx around px iphone'> 
                        <input name = 'keywords' type = 'text' id = 'search-keyword' class = 'search-keyword form-control' placeholder = 'keywords (pool, garage)'>
                        <select name = 'area' id = 'search-area' class = 'form-control'>
                            {% for key,value in area_choices.items %}
                            <option value = "{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'flx around iphone'>
                        <select name="bedrooms" class="form-control">
                            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" selected>Bedrooms(All)</option>   
                            {% for key,value in bedroom_choices.items %}
                            <option value = "{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                        <select name="price" class="form-control ">
                            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" selected>Price(All)</option>   
                            {% for key,value in price_choices.items %}
                            <option value = "{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type = "submit" class = 'btn fntmk my2 size'>Search&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-search size"></i></button>
                </form>
```

view:

```
from .choices import price_choices, bedroom_choices, area_choices
    def search(request):
        queryset_list = Oglas.objects.order_by('-list_date')
    
        # keywords
        if 'keywords' in request.GET:
            keywords = request.GET['keywords']
            if keywords:
                queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains = keywords)  
        # Area
        if 'area' in request.GET:
            area = request.GET['area']
            if area:
                queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(area__iexact = area)
        # rooms 
        if 'bedrooms' in request.GET:
            bedrooms = request.GET['bedrooms']
            if bedrooms:
                queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(bedrooms__lte=bedrooms) 
    
        # price
        if 'price' in request.GET:
            price = request.GET['price']
            if price:
                queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(price__lte = price)
        
        context = {
            'area_choices' : area_choices,
            'bedroom_choices' : bedroom_choices,
            'price_choices' : price_choices,
            'listings' : queryset_list,
            'values' : request.GET,
        }   
        return render(request, 'pages/search.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Form are handled completly different. You're mixing up the template with the form handling.
Have a look in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/) first. You need to add a form object into your context.

Extract from the mentioned doc:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: the form is not posting anything to db, it just fetching(compare) data. It works fine on localhost/search. The issue is on locahost/     (homepage) , there the values are empty.

Comment: Don't you have to use <form method="GET"...> in your template ?

Comment: Its search form. seems easier to me

Comment: I solved this by manually typed values and keys.